# Vb .net Error, No row in database greater than 0

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2013

I am making a vb .net winform project that uses a sql server database. A user inputs the details of a person (firstName, lastName, company, contactNumber, etc.) visiting a factory into textboxes, hits the save details button, and this saves the data in the datatable. This works fine, the problem is the next part. The user is then redirected to another form where the input details are shown from the database. This works for the first record but not for any record input after that, I get an error that says "There is no row at position 'n'" and the following line of code is highlighted in the form_Load:

```
txtFirstName.Text = CStr(dtVisitorDetails.Rows(CInt(CDbl(txtIdNumber.Text) - 1)).Item(1))
```

It is telling me that any rows after row 0 are not there but I know they are because I have input them and they are showing up in the datatable in the sql server database manager.
I cannot sort this problem, any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I am attaching the rest of the code that's involved with this problem.
Thanks in advanced.

```
Private Sub previousVisitor_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

connectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLExpress;InitialCatalog=Visitors;" & _
"IntegratedSecurity=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"

sqlVisitorDetails = "SELECT * FROM visitorDetails WHERE idNumber=@idNumber"

    sqlCon.Open()
    sqlCmd = New SqlCommand(sqlVisitorDetails, sqlCon)
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idNumber", txtIdNumber.Text)

    dtVisitorDetails = loadDtVisitorDetails()

    txtFirstName.Text = CStr(dtVisitorDetails.Rows(CInt(CDbl(txtIdNumber.Text) - 1)).Item(1))
    txtLastName.Text = CStr(dtVisitorDetails.Rows(CInt(CDbl(txtIdNumber.Text) - 1)).Item(2))
    txtCompany.Text = CStr(dtVisitorDetails.Rows(CInt(CDbl(txtIdNumber.Text) - 1)).Item(3))
    txtContactNumber.Text = CStr(dtVisitorDetails.Rows(CInt(CDbl(txtIdNumber.Text) - 1)).Item(4))
    txtCountryCode.Text = CStr(dtVisitorDetails.Rows(CInt(CDbl(txtIdNumber.Text) - 1)).Item(5))
    txtEmail.Text = CStr(dtVisitorDetails.Rows(CInt(CDbl(txtIdNumber.Text) - 1)).Item(7))

    sqlCmd.Dispose()
    sqlCon.Close()

End Sub

Private Function loadDtVisitorDetails() As DataTable
    Dim dtVisitorDetails As DataTable = Nothing

    sqlVisitorDetails = "SELECT * FROM visitorDetails WHERE idNumber=" & txtIdNumber.Text

    dtVisitorDetails = fillDtVisitorDetails(sqlVisitorDetails)

    Return dtVisitorDetails
End Function

Public Function fillDtVisitorDetails(ByVal sqlVisitorDetails As String) As DataTable

    Dim dtVisitorDetails As New DataTable
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim conCmd As New SqlCommand

    conCmd.CommandText = sqlVisitorDetails

    da.SelectCommand = conCmd
    da.SelectCommand.Connection = sqlCon

    dtVisitorDetails.Columns.GetEnumerator()
    da.Fill(dtVisitorDetails)

    Return dtVisitorDetails
End Function
```

Comment: What is the value of `txtIdNumber.Text` at this point?

Comment: It is anything greater than 1.

Comment: If     txtIdNumber.Text is 1 it works fine, but anything greater than 1 it will throw up the error "No row at position 'n'"

Comment: OK, when you insert rows, can you insert more than one row for one value of `IdNumber`?

Comment: No, each row has an unique ID number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can only have 1 row for each unique ID number, when you search and filter as `WHERE idNumber = ID Number in form`, you should get at most 1 record. That means the `DataTable` can have at most 1 row.

When you access the `Rows` of a `DataTable` like `dt.Rows(ID)`, you are trying to access the row at position number `ID` in the collection of rows. Therefore, when you do `dtVisitorDetails.Rows(CInt(CDbl(txtIdNumber.Text) - 1)` for any value of ID number greater than 1, it will fail because that index simply does not exist in the table.

Instead, you should directly use `dtVisitorDetails.Rows(0)` to access the row. Since you have filtered by the ID Numberm you will only get the details for that person by doing so. Finally, remember to add a check for the row count in the table, so that if you search for an ID which has no records, there will not be an error in trying to retrieve from the table.

Pseudo-code:

```
If dtVisitorDetails.Rows.Count > 0
 txtFirstName.Text = CStr(dtVisitorDetails.Rows(0).Item(1))
 ...
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't follow. What do you mean by 'for any value of ID number greater than 1, it will fail for sure because the index simply does not exist in the table'???

Comment: I have updated my answer. Basically, table has maximum 1 row, so `Rows(ID-1)` will give error if ID > 1.

Comment: I have the count sorted on another form where you enter the ID number and hit search. Are you saying that if I put '0' in for rows instead of (txtIdNumber.Text) - 1) that it should work properly?

Comment: Thank you very much, I changed (txtIdNumber.Text) - 1) to '0'. I thought that if I put in '0'  that it would show up row '0'(i.e. ID number 1) each time, where as it will actually show the row I have queried in my sql statement. Thank you so much for your help.